# how to create laravel-echo connection in nodejs with pusher?

Tags: node.js, laravel, axios, pusher, laravel-echo

I want to communicate my nodejs backend with frontend with laravel-echo and pusher
I need to use laravel because backend developer has created a php backend with laravel, and he passed me the pusher information and i put them in .env

the doc of laravel isnt very helpful on this, maybe i am too new to this, I followed the way in the doc to create an echo connection with pusher with the code the below. But i got an error saying Echo is not a constructor.

The flow goes like this, frontend A.html will call a fetch to trigger the nodejs backend to run a python script. upon the python script returned stdout, will trigger nodejs backend to post a message to a frontend B.html that is listening to the laravel channel.

in the frontend B.html:

```
<script>
var channel = Echo.channel('chat');
        channel.listen('response', function (data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            <<do sth with the data>>
</script>
```

in the nodejs backend index.js:

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
import axios from 'axios';

global.axios = axios;
global.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
global.pusher = Pusher;

global.Echo = new Echo({ //throw 'Echo is not a constructor' error
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME,
    wsPort: 80,
    wssPort: 443,
});

var channel = Echo.channel('chat');
channel.listen('response', function (data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

app.get('/record', (req, res) => {
    const pyProg = spawn('python', ['script.py']);
    pyProg.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        const data_string = data.toString();
        const data_json = JSON.parse(data_string);
        const message = data_json.message;
        axios.post('/api/post', {
            type: 'MESSAGE',
            value: message,
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            message.value = "";
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
        return res.json({ success: true, data: data_string });
    });
});
```

My questions are

How can i connect to the laravel backend with laravel-echo and pusher and then broadcast a message from node backend to frontend that is listening to the channel?

What is the proper way to create the echo channel in nodejs backend?

Thanks